# Reading a json response with multiple objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON response as below.

```
{
   returnCode: 'Success',
   info: null,
   result: {
       payload: '{
            "BatchNo":"143123",
            "Supplier":"Automotive",
            "ItemNumber":"AP123",
            "ProdNumber":"\\"\\"",
            "ItemIdentifier":"PROCURE"}             
            {
            "BatchNo":"143123",
            "Supplier":"Manufacturing",
            "ItemNumber":"API124",
            "ProdNumber":"PRD123",
            "ItemIdentifier":"PRODUCE"}',
 encode: 'UTF-8'
 },
  txid:'8d9efd6083e6ca737e9c751baecd0c75cf738e9ce0e599bcfa26910575fa6d5f8d9efd6083e'
}
```

Please note, there are no arrays [{}] in the JSON data. Can someone help me how I can access `result.payload.ItemNumber` values and get an output like

```
AP123
AP124
```

I tried below code, but in vain. Somebody please help me

```
 var output1 = JSON.parse(json).result.payload[1].ItemNumber;
 console.log("Data:"+ output1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `payload` is a string, but not a well-formed JSON string. It looks like it's almost an array but missing the container: `[ ]` and no comma between objects. The best way forward would be to fix your data so it's valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

### Note

Had to clean up the payload and convert it into an array with a comma separated the list of objects.  Otherwise, it is invalid response data.

### Code

```js
let json = {
   returnCode: 'Success',
   info: null,
   result: {
       payload: '[{"BatchNo":"143123","Supplier":"Automotive","ItemNumber":"AP123","ProdNumber":"\\"\\"","ItemIdentifier":"PROCURE"},{"BatchNo":"143123","Supplier":"Manufacturing","ItemNumber":"API124","ProdNumber":"PRD123","ItemIdentifier":"PRODUCE"}]',
        encode: 'UTF-8'
 },
  txid:'8d9efd6083e6ca737e9c751baecd0c75cf738e9ce0e599bcfa26910575fa6d5f8d9efd6083e'
}

 var output1 = JSON.parse(json.result.payload)[1].ItemNumber;
 console.log("Data:"+ output1);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to add the necessary [ ]  and "," to make it a valid json array value. And I was able to access the values using json.parse command mentioned above